# Track state of time series event in SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time-series

This seems really simple but I can't figure it out, working in SQL Server. I have time series data and I want a column to track the state of ON/OFF events for each row, so when there's an ON event then the Desired Output column will have a 1 for each subsequent event until there is an OFF event. Please see example below. Thanks so much!

| TimeStamp | Event | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1:01 | ON | 1 |
| 1:02 | OFF | 0 |
| 1:04 | other | 0 |
| 1:05 | other | 0 |
| 1:06 | ON | 1 |
| 1:10 | other | 1 |
| 1:12 | other | 1 |
| 1:14 | OFF | 0 |
| 1:15 | other | 0 |

Comment: Consider using Temporal Tables instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/temporal-tables

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL saves us from guessing data types, e.g. for `TimeStamp`. Can an `'ON'` or `'OFF'` `Event` repeat, e.g. two `'OFF'` events without an intervening `'ON'`?

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I apologize I'm still new with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  flagged AS
(
  SELECT
    timestamp,
    CASE WHEN event = 'ON'  THEN 1
         WHEN event = 'OFF' THEN 0 END   AS state
  FROM
    #table
),
  cumulative AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(state) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)   AS state_group
  FROM
    flagged
)
SELECT
  timestamp,
  MAX(state) OVER (PARTITION BY state_group)   AS persisted_state
FROM
  cumulative
```

Comment: Wow, this is 100% brilliant! I tried my loop method on a subset of data and the query took 19s, vs just 3s with this method. Works awesome, thanks so much!

Comment: @TrafficDataAnalyst - Do you have an index on the timestamp?

Comment: No, timestamp is not indexed. This is a one off use case with potential for production later, so performance is not critical for now but may be later.

Comment: In case you're curious, i'm working with traffic light data where ON and OFF are sensors detecting vehicles, and I want to know how long the sensor was on during the green light, and if the sensor stays on after the light turns red because that implies not everyone was able to make it through the light.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the cumulative count of ONs and OFFs:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when event = 'ON' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by timestamp) >
                  sum(case when event = 'OFF' then 1 else 0 end)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as desired
from t;
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks so much for the response! This works perfectly for the problem I presented. As I'm implementing it however I am finding I didn't consider all the possibilities, such as there could be two ON events in a row. I think the final solution is actually to iterate through using a WHILE loop

Answer (score 0):

I realized there could actually be two ON events in a row, or sometimes entries can be missing. So to track the state of this event I think using a WHILE loop may be the best option.

```
WHILE @CurrentRow <= @TotalRows
BEGIN
    SELECT @DesiredOutput = CASE WHEN Event = 'ON' THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN Event = 'OFF' THEN 0 ELSE @DesiredOutput END END
    FROM #Table
    WHERE @CurrentRow = Row_Number

    UPDATE #Table
    SET DesiredOutput = @DesiredOutput
    WHERE @CurrentRow = Row_Number
    
    SET @CurrentRow += 1
END
```

Comment: Loops are bad, mmkay. I'll add a set-based answer for you, but I'm on my phone, give me "a moment".